# Publishing image data using bunch of images in directory

Tags: ros, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I'm thinking to make 'dataset player' which is playing individual frame file to image topic.
For example, the dataset from http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/karlsruhe_sequences.html, to virtual camera to test various algorithm.
However, I think it would be tedious job...
Before I'm doing so, please let me know any related package with this.
It would be nice!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42218/publishing-image-data-using-bunch-of-images-in-directory/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tried it, but this looks promising: http://code.google.com/p/seabee3-ros-pkg/wiki/image_server

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0